# Didn't get response from dataTaskPublisher with URLSession in Swift

Tags: swift

I was trying to use dataTaskPublisher in my project.

I already use dataTask successfully.

This is the code that I use it, it works when I use dataTask, but in this case with dataTaskPublisher it didn't get response from the print statements. Why is this happening ?

```
    var cancels: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    let request = URLSessionHelper.getRequestWithUrl(endpointUrl: url, httpMethod: HTTPMethod.get, jsonBodyData: nil)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionHelper.sessionConfiguration, delegate: SessionDelegate(), delegateQueue: nil)
    
    session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map(\.data)
        .compactMap { String(data: $0, encoding:. utf8) }
        
        .sink { error in
                    print("error: \(error)")
                    // Cannot assign value of type 'Subscribers.Completion<Error>' to type 'Error?'
                 } receiveValue: { resutl in
                     print("resutl: \(resutl)")
                 }
        .store(in: &cancels)
```

Comment: Is `session` going out of scope? What happens if you store a reference to it?

Comment: How can I store a reference to session ? Just like that "let variable = session.dataTaskPublisher ..." , is this correct?

Comment: No -- store the session (not the publisher) in an instance variable on whatever class you're on. I'm not sure, by the way, that this will solve it, but it's worth a try. You may already be doing this, but your code isn't clear on this.

Comment: @jnpdx You are right, this is the answer to the question. I put the variable as a instance variable and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session` is going immediately out-of-scope -- the Combine chain doesn't hold a strong reference to it.

You should store a reference to it as an instance variable on your class, which will prevent this problem.